# What is a proper curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

In the language of Janos Kollar's ``[Rational curves on algebraic varieties](https://books.google.com/books?id=ux_4CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA135&dq=irreducible%20proper%20curve&pg=PA100#v=onepage&q=proper%20curve&f=false),'' what is the definition of a *proper curve*? Is it possible to understand this without using the language of schemes?

Comment: For simplicity, let us assume that you are working with varieties over a filed $k$. Then to say $X$ is proper (over $k$) means for any other variety $T$ over $k$, the natural map $X\times_k T\to T$ is closed. That is, image of a closed set of the former maps on to a closed subset of $T$. This should be true for ANY $T$.

Comment: Thanks, isn't that the definition of a proper map or morphism though?

Comment: Proper is always over something, what I described is proper over the field $k$, in other words, the morphism $X\to \mathrm{Spec} k$ is proper.

Comment: Is X in your answer a curve (making it proper)? Alternatively, can it be a surface (making it a "proper surface")?